# cor.test function using apply for iterating x and y vectors

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to do correlation using cor.test function as follows:

For each character string from the object mr, I choose one object (mr1) and find corresponding targets for this mr1 from the expression dataset, and create new object, mr.tgt.

Now, for each of character string in mr.tgt, cor.test is perfomred between two numeric vectors, 1. matched gene expression values to mr.tgt[i] and 2. matched mirna expression values to mr1(or mr[i]).

Finally, table is written for relevant values.

```
mr <- c("1p","2p","3p",...)

mr.tgt.pval.function <- function(mr){
  file.out <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

  for(i in 1:length(mr)){        
    mr1 <- as.character(mr[i])
    mr.tgt <- c("a","b","c",..) # mr.tgt %in% mr = 0 & mr.tgt changes with each of mr1[i]

    for(i in 1:length(mr.tgt)){
      cor.result.pval <- cor.test(as.numeric(expr[which(rownames(expr) == mr.tgt[i]),]),
                        as.numeric(mir[which(rownames(mir) == mr1),]), 
                                   method="spearman", alternative="less", exact=NULL, continuity=T)
      write.table(cbind(mr1,mr.tgt[i],cor.result.pval$p.value,cor.result.pval$estimate[[1]]),file = file.out, sep="\t", na='', append=T,col.names=FALSE)
    }  
  }  
}
```

I am trying to use apply function for cor.test but having difficulty iterating for each of mr.tgt[i] within each of mr[i].

```
apply(?matched.expr.vector.mr.tgt.for.each.of.mr[i],
2,function(x) cor.test(?,?,method="spearman",alternative="l"))
```

I wanted to see if I can use apply function to overcome slow data processing with for loop.

Much appreciate helpful hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Both the outer and inner for-loops use `i`. Not great, but it can actually still work as expected.

Comment: It seems you use `expr` and `mir` - what are those, and why aren't they arguments to the function?

Comment: Thanks Tommy for looking into the code. `expr` and `mir` are data.frames from which I am extracting matching expression values to `mr.tgt` (mirna gene target) and `mr1`(mirna), respectively. I should switch to `i` and `j` instead of keeping `i` for both loops.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very likely that the for-loop overhead is the bottleneck. I suspect the time in  `write.table` dominates, although the `cor.test` could be slow too.

Try commenting out the `write.table` part and see how fast it becomes. If that "solves" the problem, try assembling the table in the loop and write it afterwards.